# Cannot build "chaintool/example02"

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to follow instructions on [Chaincode Development Environment](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/blob/master/docs/setup.md) to setup hyperledger in my local environment.

Unfortunately, I am completely new to *golang*. When I come across an error trying to build "*chaintool/example02*" I have no idea how to proceed further - should I ignore the issue or first I should fix something? For example, to run make with some options, etc ... How can I get missing imports ?

The output looks as follows:

```
hyper-00:chaincode hyper$ pwd
 /Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/chaintool/example02/src/chaincode

hyper-00:chaincode hyper$ go build ./
    chaincode_example02.go:24:2: cannot find package "hyperledger/cci/appinit" in any of:
        /Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/hyperledger/cci/appinit (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/hyperledger/cci/appinit (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/hyperledger/cci/appinit (from $GOPATH)
    chaincode_example02.go:25:2: cannot find package "hyperledger/cci/org/hyperledger/chaincode/example02" in any of:
        /Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/hyperledger/cci/org/hyperledger/chaincode/example02 (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/hyperledger/cci/org/hyperledger/chaincode/example02 (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/hyperledger/cci/org/hyperledger/chaincode/example02 (from $GOPATH)
    chaincode_example02.go:26:2: cannot find package "hyperledger/ccs" in any of:
        /Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/hyperledger/ccs (vendor tree)
        /usr/local/go/src/hyperledger/ccs (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/hyperledger/ccs (from $GOPATH)
hyper-00:chaincode hyper$
```

My $GOPATH gives:

```
hyper-00:~ hyper$ echo $GOPATH 
/Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain
```

---

**[EDITED on 2017-01-02]**

I repeated the repo cloning procedure again. 
I think my mistake was I pulled a wrong source from GitHub - probably "*master*", not "*v0.6*".

What I did and the compilation works now is:

```
$ sudo apt install golang-go

$ gedit .profile

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/Projects/blockchain    

$ . ~/.profile

$ mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/

$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger

$ git clone -b v0.6 http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric

$ cd ~/Projects/blockchain/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 

$ go build
```

Comment: Did you checked your `$GOPATH` ?

Comment: I have it set in my .profile. I added it to my post at the end.

Comment: in the `example02`, the code will try to import `shim` from `"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"` which is not in your `$GOPATH`. This is why you got this error.

Comment: I think I have it: `/Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim` but what worries me is `cannot find package "hyperledger/cci/appinit"`. Should I clone additional repo from github beforehand?

Comment: I din't use this package. So, maybe you've to clone some additional packages. Try it and leave your feedbacks.

Comment: congrats on the fix and welcome to smart contracts! if you like you can check out a totally different stack called Eris at [monax.io](https://monax.io)

Answer (score 2):

`github.com/hyperledger/fabric` should have included all these dependencies in its `vendor/` folder or put the examples in their own repo with a vendor folder, so this looks like their problem not yours.

You can fix it by running  `go get x y z` for all missing packages, or try using a vendoring tool to get them.

There are many options for vendoring but no "official" option until next year. I prefer `govendor`. i havent tried it with this particular repo but you can try with:

```
go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor
cd /Users/hyper/Projects/blockchain/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/
govendor fetch -v +missing
```

Answer (score 2):

The HyperLedger team has provided very good documentation on how to use chaintool in a manner that allows users to document APIs (via Chain Code Interface, or CCI).  Without this, consumers of a chaincode must inspect source code to understand how to compose a REST invocation.  Great idea.

This approach to building chaincode requires you download github.com/hyperledger/cci and github.com/hyperledger/ccs to reside next to github.com/hyperledger/fabric within your $GOPATH.  Unfortunately, I don't see any repository (on either github or gerrit) where this can be downloaded.

Further, I've only seen one example (thus far) of how to use chaintool with cci and ccs, which is chaintool/example02... and it does not compile due to these missing hyperledger packages.

There is documentation on chaintool with cci/ccs support at the following location:

- https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaintool

But it seems this documentation has been copied to the following location and renamed from 'chaintool' to 'openblockchain compiler' (or OBCC) and labeled as a 'work in progress':

- https://libraries.io/github/hyperledger/fabric-chaintool

As such, I am inclined to believe the chaintool/example02 is not a currently supported approach to building chaincode... at least until OBCC becomes officially available.